# Javascript Image Swap not activating function

Tags: javascript, image, swap

I'm not much of a javascript coder so i am seeking any advice from anyone who may be able to help me with a problem i have, the main issue is i am trying to swap an image so that they can be selected by choosing a radio button.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function changeImage(newImage)
{
    if document[imageName].src = eval(newImage + ".src");
}
var img00700000232 = new Image();
img00700000232.src = "/2/00700000232.jpg";
var img00700000263 = new Image();
img00700000263.src = "/2/00700000263.jpg";
var img00700000270 = new Image();
img00700000270.src = "/2/00700000270.jpg";
var img00700000133 = new Image();
img00700000133.src = "images/TempImage.png";
var img00700000164 = new Image();
img00700000164.src = "images/TempImage.png";
var img00700000140 = new Image();
img00700000140.src = "images/TempImage.png";
var img00700000157 = new Image();
img00700000157.src = "images/TempImage.png";
</script>



</head><body>
<form name="test">
<input name="field" type="radio" value="00700000232" onchange="changeImage('img00700000232');">Prod1</input>
<br/>
<input name="field" type="radio" value="00700000263" onchange="changeImage('img00700000263');">Prod2</input>
<br/>
<input name="field" type="radio" value="00700000270" onchange="changeImage('img00700000270');">Prod3</input>
<br/>
<input name="field" type="radio" value="00700000133" onchange="changeImage('img00700000133');">Prod4</input>
<br/>
<input name="field" type="radio" value="00700000164" onchange="changeImage('img00700000164');">Prod5</input>
<br/>
<input name="field" type="radio" value="00700000140" onchange="changeImage('img00700000140');">Prod6</input>
<br/>
<input name="field" type="radio" value="00700000157" onchange="changeImage('img00700000157');">Prod7</input>
<br/>
</form>
<img name="image_name" src="images/TempImage.png" />
```

This is the code that is generated from ASP classic so the code is generated server side so im not sure whether this is an issue or whether there is a problem with my code, any and all help will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Brad

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error:

```
if document[imageName].src = eval(newImage + ".src");
```

should be:

```
if( document["image_name"])
  document["image_name"].src = eval(newImage + ".src");
```

EDIT:

A better way to get at the "image_name" DOM element though would be to change the 'name' attribute to 'id' and use document.getElementById instead.

So, that'd look like this:

`<img id="image_name" src="images/TempImage.png" />`

```
function changeImage(newImage) 
{
  var imgEle = document.getElementById("image_name");
  if (imgEle){
      imgEle.src = eval(newImage + ".src");
  }
}
```

Also, you don't necessarily need to use eval here.  You can reference the image variables in the Anchor tag if you want

so change this

```
<input name="field" type="radio" value="00700000164" onchange="changeImage('img00700000164');">Prod5</input>
```

to this

Prod5

which you would then have to change your function from

```
function changeImage(newImage) 
{
  var imgEle = document.getElementById("image_name");
  if (imgEle && newImage){
      imgEle.src = newImage.src;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help that solved it perfectly, also i didn't realize it was case sensitive.